# Detecting when all images have loaded in an Angular.js view

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, image, loading

I've got a view that I load which contains a substantial number of images (between 100-200 typically), so this can take around 5 seconds to fully load / render, so I want to add a loading indicator during that time.

My problem is, I can't seem to find a reliable way of knowing when to present the view and hide the loading indicator. Previously, I'd used this piece of [jQuery] code to achieve this:

`$(window).load(function() {
    $('.loading-notice').fadeOut(300, function () {
        $('.library-thumbnails').fadeIn(1000);
    });
});`

Which worked great - however this isn't usable when loading a view in via Angular.js it seems.

I've got my Angular.js template and controller setup fine to do the fading in and out in the same style of which I did using jQuery, but I just can't detect when the images have all finished loading is all - I can only seem to detect when the JSON is returned from the server that will be used in the model.

**EDIT**
I should have mentioned, I also tried using $viewContentLoaded as per below, however this is called before the images finish loading.

`$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
        console.log('$viewContentLoaded');
    });`

Comment: `window.onload` doesn't work in Angular because the window doesn't reload, the content is populated dynamically. What you probably want instead is `$viewContentLoaded`

Comment: @adeneo sorry, I should have mentioned I had tried that (see edited post now), thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Hey @rastating, did you try my response?

Answer (score 0):

### Resource: ngLoading

A good friend of mine at Hack Reactor ([Mason Hargrove](https://github.com/maseh87)) created an Angular directive called [ngLoading](https://github.com/maseh87/ng-loading) that you can drop in for purposes just like this.

Here's what it does:

> ngLoading will listen to any http request made from your application and show the animation, when your application recieves the http response it will remove the animation.

### Step-by-Step

1. Install ngLoading:

   ```
   bower install ng-loading --save
   ```
2. Inject `ngLoading` as a dependency to your main module:

   ```
   angular.module('myApp', ['ngLoading']);
   ```
3. (Optional) If the images are not rendering quickly-enough to the template after the `$http` request is done, you could continue the loading screen (hacky and probably unnecessary):

   ```
   .controller('MyController', function(Interceptor, $timeout) {
     //trigger the loading screen to start
     Interceptor.start();

     // Give the images time, 4 seconds, to render
     $timeout(Interceptor.end, 4000)
   });
   ```

### Result

While the images load from the server, the loader graphic will automatically display. It will stop when the `$http` request is done.

#### Futher Reading

Here's an [interesting discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/734) for an Angular feature request, asking for "a way to detect if Angular finished rendering of HTML DOM." They generally suggest the use of `$timeout` as a workaround.